# Junit test cases for Rest API using Junit and Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

**Junit test cases for API's**

I'm new to Junit and Mockito, trying to write unit test cases for my controller class to test my APIs.

**Here is the controller class**

```java
    package com.mylearnings.controller;
    
    import com.mylearnings.modal.Product;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @RestController
    public class ProductController {
    
        private HashMap<String, Product> productCatalog = new HashMap<>();
    
        @PostMapping("/product")
        public ResponseEntity addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
            productCatalog.put(product.getId(), product);
            return new ResponseEntity("product added successfully", HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity getProductDetails(@PathVariable String id) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(productCatalog.get(id));
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/product")
        public List<Product> getProductList() {
            return new ArrayList<>(productCatalog.values());
        }
    
        @PutMapping("/product")
        public String updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
            productCatalog.put(product.getId(), product);
            return "product updated successfully";
        }
    
        @DeleteMapping("/product/{id}")
        public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
            productCatalog.remove(id);
            return "product deleted successfully";
        }
    }
```

**I have tried the following**
Added @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) and tried but still it's failing

```java
    package com.mylearnings.controller;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.mylearnings.modal.Product;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
    import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
    
    import java.util.Map;
    
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
    
    @SpringBootTest
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    public class ProductControllerTest {
    
        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    
        @Mock
        private Map<String, Product> productCatalog;
    
        @InjectMocks
        private ProductController productController;
    
        @Test
        public void testAddProduct() throws Exception {
            MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/product").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new Product("MS116", "Dell MS116", "Dell MS116 Usb wired optical mouse", "", 229d)))).andReturn();
    
            assertEquals(201, mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus());
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testGetProductDetails() throws Exception {
            Product product = new Product("MS116", "Dell MS116", "Dell MS116 Usb wired optical mouse", "", 229d);
            when(productCatalog.get("MS116")).thenReturn(product);
            MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/product/{id}", "MS116").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();
    
            assertEquals(200, mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus());
            Product result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Product.class);
            assertEquals(product, result);
        }
    }
```

the test case testGetProductDetails() is failing, I'm not sure whether it is because of map?

Comment: what is the error you are getting in logs or console ?

Comment: @Deadpool this is the error I'm getting in console

`No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
`


**the exception is throwing at this line**
`Product result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Product.class);` 

in **testGetProductDetails()** testcase

because response is "" empty

Comment: looks like u r having some serialization or deserialization issue

Comment: response is empty "" that's y its throwing exception, I tried printing response in console but it is empty "".

Comment: Your `productCatalog` instance is not being injected correctly into context, thus call to `ProductController` via mockMvc with id "MS116" will not trigger configured `when` logic, resulting in null instance to be returned, converted into empty String and then causing error for ObjectMapper when it tries to convert this empty String into Product instance via `new ObjectMapper().readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Product.class);`

Comment: yes @Dmitriy, you are right. Is there any other way to inject a productCatalog

Comment: I have tried using mock(HashMap.class) instead of @Mock annotation. that was also not working

Comment: Wrap you product catalog into `@Service` component with methods etc and use `@MockBean` to annotate it and make available for `MockMvc` context

Comment: @Dmitriy Is there any other way instead of creating a new service class and moving productCatalog there

Comment: @vishalkumar see answer suggested via standalone mock mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to inject mocks into Application context using (`@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`) and make it available for you `MockMvc`, you can try to init `MockMvc` in the standalone mode with the only `ProductController` instance enabled (the one that you have just mocked).

Example:

```java
package com.mylearnings.controller;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import com.mylearnings.controller.Product;
import com.mylearnings.controller.ProductController;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ProductControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private HashMap<String, Product> productCatalog;

    @InjectMocks
    private ProductController productController;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(productController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddProduct() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/product").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new Product("MS116", "Dell MS116", "Dell MS116 Usb wired optical mouse", "", 229d))))
                .andReturn();

        assertEquals(201, mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetProductDetails() throws Exception {
        Product product = new Product("MS116", "Dell MS116", "Dell MS116 Usb wired optical mouse", "", 229d);
        when(productCatalog.get("MS116")).thenReturn(product);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/product/{id}", "MS116").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

        assertEquals(200, mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus());
        Product result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Product.class);
        assertEquals(product, result);
    }

}
```